# Function not able to compute for multiple column matrix input

Tags: python, function, statistics

Does anyone have any suggestions so that I can use the following function while inputing an X matrix that has more than 1 columns (ie multiple linear regression)?

```
def AUC_calculation(X, y, index_train, index_test):
    Xtrain, ytrain = X[index_train], y[index_train]
    Xtest, ytest = X[index_test], y[index_test]
    model=model1.fit(np.c_[np.ones(len(Xtrain)), Xtrain],ytrain)
    predprob=model.predict_proba(np.c_[np.ones(len(Xtest)), Xtest])[:,1]
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(ytest, predprob, pos_label=1)
    AUC1=auc(fpr,tpr)
    return AUC1

def AUC_cross_validation(X, y, n_fold):
    str_kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_fold)
    list_auc = np.zeros(n_fold)
    for j, (index_train, index_test) in enumerate(str_kf.split(X,y)):
      list_auc[j]=AUC_calculation(X, y, index_train, index_test)
    return list_auc
```

I get this error when I try.
`AUC_cross_validation(Data1_num.drop(['loanDefault'], axis='columns'), Data1_num.loanDefault, 10)`

"None of [Int64Index([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,\n            ...\n            990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999],\n           dtype='int64', length=900)] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you need to use single varibale for each model, in your code Xtrain contains all variables. Use `for` to loop.